# how to merge multiple columns of whole page of RDLC report

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGzf4.png)
This is a RDLC Report Form and my problem is that I will can not merging of multiple columns of this report form , please give solution of my problem

I Searched Many times on internet but I did not found solution of my problem
I want marge multiple columns of RDLC Report form body part

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want merge six columns in one column just like table in RDLC Report